# How to change all other rows except the row selected by id

Tags: mysql

I have this table bellow.

```
id      title     name    active
_____   ______    _____   _____

1       kdfl      lsdf    0
2       ksdl      klsd    1
3       ewrl      oxcl    0
```

I want to query the table so that when I get the id and change the active column to 1 all the other rows active columns change to 0. Conversely if I set it to 0, all the others would change to 1.

I have tried this particular query

`UPDATE themes SET active = 1 WHERE id = 3, SET active = 0 WHERE id = 2`

Answer (score 1):

To set the record with `ID = 2` to `1` and all other to `0` do

```
UPDATE themes 
SET active = case when id = 2
                  then 1
                  else 0
             end
```

Comment: @Haza, that's a invalid comment *asking for upvote on your question*